# Determining Bases of P4

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to figure out how to find a basis of P4 in order to meet two conditions.  First, I need to find if it's possible to find a basis for P4, the polynomials of order 4 (quartics) or less, using only powers of (x − 4).  I believe this is possible, since $(x-4)^0 = 1$.
Also, I have to find if it's possible to create a basis for P4 using only polynomials with zeros at $x=2$.  I'm not entirely sure where to start for that one.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If you can do it with powers of $x-4$ then you can do it with powers of $x-2$ right?

Comment: That's a good point.  So as long as one is true, both are.

Comment: Or is the issue that the constant polynomial doesn't have any zeros?

Comment: In a flashier way, you can consider $\phi_2\in P_4^*$ defined by $\phi_2(f)=f(2)$. Since $\phi_2\ne 0$, its $\ker$ cannot contain a basis of $P_4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $f\colon P_4\to P_4$ defined by sending the polynomial $p$ to $f(p)=\hat{p}$, where
$$
\hat{p}(x)=p(x-4)
$$
It should be easy to prove that $f$ is linear (check it) and bijective (the inverse is the similar one with $x+4$ instead of $x-4$), so it transforms a basis into a basis.

What's the image of the basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$?

For the second part, consider $V=\{p\in P_4: p(2)=0\}$. Is $V=P_4$?

Comment: Okay, so that means it is definitely possible for powers of (x-4), however, for (x-2), V would be in P2, so it would not be possible.  Please correct me if I'm understanding this incorrectly.

Comment: @tibsar Correct, but I'd say it better: the polynomials vanishing at $2$ all lie in a proper subspace of $P_4$ (it has dimension $4$, by the way), so no basis can consist of such polynomials.