# Are these linear algebra questions true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Which of the following are true or false?
>
> (a) Let $H$ be a five-dimensional subspace of the ten-dimensional
>   vector space $V$. Then, every set containing seven vectors from $H$
>   must be linearly dependent.
>
> (b) Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $A$ be a the
>   matrix whose columns are the vectors in $\mathcal{B}$. Then, for every
>   vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, it is true that $[x]_{\mathcal{B}} =
>  Ax$.
>
> (c) The dimension of the vector space $\mathbb{P}_{4}$ is $4$.
>
> (d) Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix, and let $H$ be the set of *fixed
>   vectors* of $A$, that is, the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ for which
>   $Ax = x$. Then $H$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

---

I think (a) is false, but I don't really have a reason why. I think this is true because if you have an $n$-dimensional space, you only need $n$ linearly independent ones to span the space.

I think (b) is true since it looks like a definition I saw in my book. I don't have a reason why.

I know (c) is false. I'm pretty sure it's dimension 5. I have seen the proof before. EDIT: Proof here: [Determining Bases of P4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542752/determining-bases-of-p4)

I think (d) is true. Because if $Ax = x$ and $Ay = y$ then $A(x + y) = x + y$. Also the with scalar multiplication. Also, this is sort of like eigenvalues, from my understanding.

Can someone help me verify these please?

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: No it's a quiz I took. I want to calculate my grade

Comment: What is $\Bbb P_4$?

Comment: The vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) is true. If a set of $7$ vectors in $H$ were independent, they are a basis for a subspace of $H$, so that the $5$-dimensional space $H$ has a subspace of dimension $7$, which is absurd. (b) is true; $A$ is called a change of basis matrix. (c) is false for the reason you state, and (d) is true for the reason you state. Good thinking!